# Escrever em um arquivo Shell Script

Tags: linux, script, shell-script, echo, sed

Estou com um problema a respeito de escrever uma linha em um arquivo utilizando o Shell Script. Eu já tentei utilizar o sed e o echo, mas em ambos eu não tenho o comportamento esperado.

Utilizando o sed:

```
sed -i -e 'export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'' /root/.bashrc
```

Utilizando o echo:

```
echo "eval "`dircolors`"" >> /root/.bashrc
```

O que eu acredito que possa estar ocorrendo é que o sed utiliza as aspas simples (') para iniciar e finalizar o que deve ser escrito, mas como o que tenho que escrever possui aspas simples, ele não consegue entender qual deve ser o início e o final.

E utilizando o echo, como ele utiliza aspas duplas (") ao invés das simples como o sed, ele também não sabe onde é o início e o fim do que pretendo escrever.

Eu tentei declarar uma variável no script e utilizar o echo para gravar no arquivo, mas também não funcionou, eu fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
variavel=alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
```

E depois onde desejo escrever, da seguinte forma:

```
echo $variavel >> /root/.bashrc
```

Alguém sabe o que posso estar fazendo para escrever essas linhas nesse arquivo? Ou algum outro comando para utilizar no lugar do echo ou do sed.
Desde já agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

Peço desculpas caso tenha ficado desorganizado ou alguma ideia expressada de forma errada. É a minha primeira dúvida que posto aqui no stack.

Comment: "Escape" as aspas com a barra invertida *\\* ou utilize `" ' "`, ou ainda, `' " '`

Comment: Valdeir, poderia me explicar como eu realizo o uso da barra invertida ao invés das aspas? Supondo que eu fosse utilizar o echo, ficaria da seguinte maneira `echo \eval "dircolors"\ >> /root/.bashrc` ?

Comment: O Valderir quis dizer que você tem que colocar a \ na frente das aspas que você deseja adicionar no arquivo. Colocando a barra invertida você diz para o sistema mostra as aspas.<br>
Ex.:<br><br> <code>echo "eval "\\`dircolors\\`"" >> /root/.bashrc</code><br><br>
Saida<br> <code>eval 'dircolors'</code>